# How to login and enter into a different html page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js , I have a login page made in bootstrap and I also have a small validation done in a js file where it checks if the username and password is test when clicked on signin button, what I am trying to achieve now using backbone.js is once signin button is clicked with valid data it should take me to xyz.html file

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761287/backbone-js-how-to-redirect-from-one-view-to-another-view

Answer (score 0):

when  you receive your success message, in the callback just type

```
window.location='xyz.html'
```

It will forward there.  Be aware that any javascript objects will be lost, so if you need to pass data to the next page, you can do it through cookies, or url parameters (window.location='xyz.html?data=cool,stuff,to,know' ) or by having xyz.html make a request to "the server" when it starts, and get some data.

if you want to do it the backbone way, you can do:

```
myRouter.navigate("/xyz.html", true)
```

but that will not actually forward you, it will just change the url and then call the handler for that "route" because what you are then supposed to do is to do an ajax call for an html template, or otherwise rebuild the current page differently.   If you do actually want to end up on a different page then you SHOULD use window.location

Comment: I want to do it using backbone.js only

Comment: @user3724559 ok, well show your code so far.  But don't expect that using "backbone.js" will somehow exempt you from writing javascript. After all backbone is just some javascript.